# unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

Tags: scala, akka, type-erasure

I am writing tests for my `Akka` actor where my actor responds with a `Seq[Id]` (and `Id` is my `case class`).

I do

```
val generator = TestActorRef[IdGenerator]
val batchSize: Int = 10

within(10.millis) {
  generator ! GetIdentifiers(batchSize)

  expectMsgPF() {
    case ids: Seq[Id] => println(ids)
  }
}
```

When I compile my code, I get a warning like this:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/harit/IdeaProjects/identity/target/scala-2.11/test-classes...
[warn] /Users/harit/IdeaProjects/identity/src/test/scala/com/identity/business/IdGeneratorSpec.scala:32: non-variable type argument com.identity.message.Id in type pattern Seq[com.identity.message.Id] (the underlying of Seq[com.identity.message.Id]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
[warn]         case ids: Seq[Id] => println(ids)
[warn]                   ^
[warn] one warning found
```

What is the way to make it work without warning?

Answer (score 3):

Scala was defined with Type Erasure. At runtime the JVM will only see a `Seq` not its type parameter.

One way you could go a bit around it is if you wrap your `Seq[Id]` inside a case class.

```
case class MyAwesomeSeq(s: Seq[Id])
```

and pattern-match against it.